# How to test a rake task with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails, rake-task, ruby-2.1

I have an Ruby 2.1/Rails 3.2 application which uses the asset pipeline. We are also using a fragile (alpha) gem which causes "rake assets:precompile" to fail at times. I would like to write an rspec test which ensures that this rake task always passes before we commit our code.

I wrote a test in spec/asset_precompile_spec.rb which looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rake'

describe 'assets:precompile' do
  before { MyApp::Application.load_tasks }
  it { expect { Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].invoke }.not_to raise_exception }
end
```

I then ran it on the command line using

```
rspec spec/lib/assets_precompile_spec.rb
```

The output I got looked like this:

```
  1) assets:precompile 
     Failure/Error: it { expect { Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].invoke }.not_to raise_exception }
       expected no Exception, got #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [/home/railsdev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/...]> with backtrace:
         # ./spec/lib/assets_precompile_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
         # ./spec/lib/assets_precompile_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/lib/assets_precompile_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.71247 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/lib/assets_precompile_spec.rb:7 # assets:precompile
```

I have looked far & wide, and I can't find any example to run "rake assets:precompile" which actually works in my RSpec environment.  I have tried explicitly loading the spec_helper.rb file, I have tried explicitly requiring "factory_girl", but I cannot find anything which works.

Is there a way to make a test run this rake task run in a RSpec test?

Comment: I had no issue using the code you provided.

Comment: I ran into the same issue and @spr's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Rake::Task['assets:precompile:all'].invoke`

instead of `Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].invoke`

In my case it helped.